# issue while loading the messages in to MQ

Tags: ibm-mq

issue facing while  loading the messages in to mq channel,  recieving an error like below  pasted

```
MQOPEN ended with reason code 2001

unable to open queue for output
```

how can i resolve this above issue,kindly can any one please advice on the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return code resolves as follows:

```
C:\>mqrc 2001

      2001  0x000007d1  MQRC_ALIAS_BASE_Q_TYPE_ERROR
```

The [Infocenter page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/fm12080_.htm) for this return code provides the following explanation:

---

**2001 (07D1) (RC2001): MQRC_ALIAS_BASE_Q_TYPE_ERROR**

*Explanation*

An MQOPEN or MQPUT1 call was issued specifying an alias queue as the destination, but the BaseQName in the alias queue definition resolves to a queue that is not a local queue, a local definition of a remote queue, or a cluster queue. Completion Code

*MQCC_FAILED Programmer response*

Correct the queue definitions.

---

In other words, the queue your app is opening is an alias queue. If you are opening for input and the base queue is not a local queue, this error results.  If you are opening for output and the base queue is not  a local queue, a local definition of a remote queue, or a cluster queue you also get this error.

What is not mentioned in the error code above is that if the alias queue points directly to a transmit queue you also get this error. In that case what you need is a QRemote and not an alias.